# How do I add custom emmet snippets in VSCode?

Tags: html, jsx, visual-studio-code, emmet

As per [october 2020 changelog](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_51#_emmet) it's possible to add custom snippets for VSCode.
Let's say I have `snippets.json` located in `workspace\configs\emmet` with the content like this:

```json
{
  "html": {
    "snippets": {
      "btn:b|button:button|button:b": "button[type={button}] ${1}"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to link its path in the `.code-workpace` file OS-agnostic way, so using a bunch of [VSCode variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference):

```json
{
  "settings": {
    "emmet.extensionsPath": "${workspaceFolder}${pathSeparator}configs${pathSeparator}emmet"
  }
}
```

But this new snippet doesn't show up in suggestions. What gives?

Comment: the `emmet.extensionsPath` needs to use the unix version of uri like `/d:/dir1/dir2`

Comment: `${workspaceFolder}` refers to the workspace folder of the current file not of `.code-workpace` file

Comment: Requiring the full path is hella annoying, since I wanted to have shareable snippets scoped to particular project.

Comment: I don't think that variables are allowed in settings properties

Comment: Did you ever discover if project specific snippets are possible or not?

Comment: No, the path you have to show is the absolute path. I guess you can call it "project-specific" if the project is a VM image. As far as plug-n-play approach - no. I guess it can somewhat work if `.code-workspace` is listed in `.gitignore` so you can put whatever you wish in your workspace config. Won't be shareable, but scoped to the project at least.

Comment: Guess I was wrong about absolute path, relative one works fine too. 
Setting `settings.emmet.extensionsPath` to something like `["./config/emmet"]` (assuming it is a folder with `snippets.json`) in `.code-workspace` file works with caveats. It seems to override default snippets and only work in `.html` (despite the docs saying they should propagate to other templates like PUG). If it requires setting the path to the default snippets we are back to square one, but nonetheless it seems to be a progress in teh right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In The VS code menu, click on File -> Preferences -> User Snippets,

and then add the snippet like this:

```
"<snippets name>": {
        "scope":  "< e.g javascript,typescript,vue,coffeescript,typescriptreact>",
        "prefix": "<your prefix>",
        "body": [
                "<snippet body"
        ]
},
```

Comment: emmet snippets are handled in a different way than regular snippets.

Comment: Even if it would've worked, the whole point behind the idea is to have project-specific snippets, so editing VSCode settings directly is a no-no.

Answer (score 0):

As of May 2023, you can have the `emmet.extensionsPath` to contain relative paths so in your .code-workspace you could add `./configs/emmet` to the array of paths